# Restrict Multiple Cell Edit - SWTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How to restrict multiple cell edit(swipe) in `SWTableViewCell` as shown in the image below. As when one cell is swiped and other cell is being swiping, the previous cell should closed itself.

Library source: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

[image]

Comment: self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;

Comment: Tried, It ain't working with this library.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
cell.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

You also need to include this delegate function :

```
- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell
{
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to set the cell's delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Could you share the the lines of code where you are setting this ? Because I am using this in my app. It works

Comment: checking for the same, function gets called but not hides, tried with putting breakpoint. If I try putting breakpoint then works but if I execute without breakpoint it dosen't work.

Comment: @BhargavSoni : Interesting :) Can you once check the delegate functions.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, are you setting cell.delegate = self; ? Check my updated answer for this

Comment: Yes, I do setting it.